# view.setBackgroundColor() is not working in android

Tags: android, listview

I have two lists `listArray` and `itemStateList`.

`listArray` is containing text to display in `ListView` and `itemStateList` is containing color names to set the background in the `ListView`. but `setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#AAFF7F"))` is not working.

Here is the code..

```
public void createAndSetAdapter(){

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listArray);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    for(int i = 0; i < listArray.size(); i++){
        switch (itemStateList.get(i)){
            case "Green_color":
                listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, listView).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#AAFF7F"));
                break;
            case "red_color":
                listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, listView).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FFAAAA"));
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Just to check if `listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, listView)` is returning a view or not, i run `((TextView)listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, listView)).getText.toString()` and it returned the text.

Comment: Use setBackgroundRes. It will work.

Comment: @AslamHossin, would You please explain. i am just learning android. don't know what is setBackgroundRes.

Comment: setBackgroundResource and setBackgroundColor both use the same api setBackgroundDrawable internally to do their tasks. So one overwrites the other. So you wont be able to achieve your goal using this api.You will have to use setBackgroundResource with a custom drawable. so create a backgroud drawable xml based on your desired color andr use it like this view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_color);

Comment: @AslamHossin, `setBackgroundResource(R.color.green_color)` is not working.

Comment: See my full answer code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all create a xml file in drawable Like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listview_background_shape">
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#ffffff" />
    <padding
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="@color/Transparent80" />
</shape>
```

Then use it as

```
listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, listView).setBackgroundResource(R.drawbale.xml_color_bg);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this:

```
listView.getAdapter().getView(i, null, listView).setBackgroundResource(R.color.black);
```

Hope this helps !!